# Most general solution to the equation $f(x) = f(1/x)$

Tags: functional-equations

What is the most general solution of the functional equation $$f(x) = f(1/x)$$ for $x>0$?

Comment: Take any function at all on the interval $(0,1]$.  Then define it for larger $x$ via your functional equation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be any set, let $g\colon(0,1]\to A$ be any function and define $f\colon (0,\infty)\to A$ by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&\text{if }x\le 1\\g(\frac1x)&\text{if }x>1\end{cases} $$

Comment: This way, $f$ is automatically continuous. What if we demand $f$ to be smooth? Do we get any restrictions?

Comment: @LBO why should $f$ be continuous?

Comment: @LBO In general, my $f$ will not be continuous (after all, adding the condition of continuity would lessen the generality)

Comment: Actually, $f$ is continuous if and only if $g$ is continuous.